# Is >&- more efficient than >/dev/null?

Tags: shell, file-descriptors

Yesterday I read [this SO comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592620/how-to-check-if-a-program-exists-from-a-bash-script/677212#comment10662979_677212) which says that in the shell (at least `bash`) `>&-` "has the same result as" `>/dev/null`.

That comment actually refers to [the ABS guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html) as the source of its information. But that source says that the `>&-` syntax "closes file descriptors".

It is not clear to me whether the two actions of closing a file descriptor and redirecting it to the null device are totally equivalent. So my question is: are they?

On the surface of it it seems that closing a descriptor is like closing a door but redirecting it to a null device is opening a door to limbo! The two don't seem exactly the same to me because if I see a closed door, I won't try to throw anything out of it, but if I see an open door I will assume I can.

In other words, I have always wondered if `>/dev/null` means that `cat mybigfile >/dev/null` would actually process every byte of the file and write it to `/dev/null` which forgets it. On the other hand, if the shell encounters a closed file descriptor I tend to think (but am not sure) that it will simply not write anything, though the question remains whether `cat` will still *read* every byte.

[This comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/70963/difference-between-2-2-dev-null-dev-null-and-dev-null-21#comment103354_70971) says `>&-` and `>/dev/null` "*should*" be the same, but it is not so resounding answer to me. I'd like to have a more authoritative answer with some reference to standard or source core or not...

Comment: If I wanted to be charitable, I'd say that the comment didn't mean that they were implemented the same way, just that they both have the same end result of preventing you from seeing the program's output.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

No, you certainly *don't* want to close file descriptors 0, 1 and 2.

If you do so, the first time the application opens a file, it will become stdin/stdout/stderr...

For instance, if you do:

```
echo text | tee file >&-
```

When `tee` (at least some implementations, like busybox') opens the file for writing, it will be open on file descriptor 1 (stdout). So `tee` will write `text` twice into `file`:

```
$ echo text | strace tee file >&-
[...]
open("file", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 1
read(0, "text\n", 8193)                 = 5
write(1, "text\n", 5)                   = 5
write(1, "text\n", 5)                   = 5
read(0, "", 8193)                       = 0
exit_group(0)                           = ?
```

That has been known to cause security vulnerabilities. For instance:

```
chsh 2>&-
```

And `chsh` (a setuid application) may end up writing error messages in `/etc/passwd`.

Some tools and even some libraries try to guard against that. For instance GNU `tee` will move the file descriptor to one above 2 if the files it opens for writing are assigned 0, 1, 2 while busybox `tee` won't.

Most tools, if they can't write to  stdout (because for instance it's not open), will report an error message on stderr (in the language of the user which means extra processing to open and parse localisation files...), so it will be significantly less efficient, and possibly cause the program to fail.

In any case, it won't be more efficient. The program will still do a `write()` system call. It can only be more efficient if the program gives up writing to stdout/stderr after the first failing `write()` system call, but programs generally don't do that. They generally either exit with an error or keep on trying.

Comment: I think this answer would be even better if the final paragraph was at the top (since it is what most directly answers the OP's question), and it then went on to discuss why it's a bad idea even if it did mostly work. But I'll take it, have an upvote. ;)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: As Michael said, I'd have expected the last para on top, but thanks for clarifying it actually probably only creates problems. So I guess an ancillary question would be, when will closing an FD actually be useful? Or should I ask that as a separate question?

Comment: @jamadagni, see http://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A22565+%223%3E%26-%22 for some examples

Comment: @jamadagni If the link provided by Stéphane doesn't answer the question, I would say that sounds like the beginnings of a separate question as it isn't directly related to the relative efficiency of the two methods.

Comment: I appreciate that Stephane starts with this vert important security warning, as it would be less visible if the last paragraph was on top. +1 from me.

Answer (score 14):

> IOW I have always wondered if `>/dev/null` means that `cat mybigfile >/dev/null` would actually process every byte of the file and write it to `/dev/null` which forgets it.

It's not a full answer to your question, but yes, the above is how it works.

`cat` reads the named file(s), or standard input if no files are named, and outputs *to its standard output* the contents of those until it encounters an EOF on (including standard input) the last file named. That is *its* job.

By adding `>/dev/null` you are redirecting standard output to /dev/null. That is a special file (a device node) which throws away anything written in it (and immediately returns EOF on read). Note that I/O redirection is a feature provided by the shell, not by each individual application, and that there is nothing magical about the *name* /dev/null, only what happens to exist there on most [Unix-like systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix-like).

It's also important to note that the specific mechanics of device nodes vary from operating system to operating system, but cat (which, in a GNU system, means coreutils) is cross-platform (the same source code needs to run *at least* on Linux and Hurd) and hence cannot take dependencies to specific operating system kernels. Additionally, it still works if you create a /dev/null alias (on Linux, this means a device node with the same major/minor device number) with another name. And there's always the case of writing somewhere else that behaves effectively the same (say, /dev/zero).

It follows that `cat` is unaware of the special properties of /dev/null, and indeed likely is unaware of the redirection in the first place, but **it still needs to perform exactly the same work:** it reads the named files, and outputs the content of the/those file(s) to its standard output. That the standard output of `cat` happens to go into a void is not something `cat` itself is concerned with.

Comment: To extend your answer: Yes, `cat mybigfile > /dev/null` will cause `cat` to read every byte of `bigfile` into memory. And, for every _`n`_ bytes, it will call `write(1, buffer, n)`. Unbeknownst to the `cat` program, the `write` will do absolutely nothing (except maybe for some trivial bookkeeping). Writing to `/dev/null` does not require processing every byte.

Comment: I remember I was blown away when I read the Linux kernel source of the /dev/null device.  I was expecting there to be some elaborate system of free()ing buffers, etc., but, no, it's just basically a return().

Comment: @G-Man: I don't know that you can guarantee that to be true in all cases.  I can't find evidence now, but I recall some implementation of either `cat` or `cp` that would work by `mmap`ing big chunks of the source file into memory, then calling `write()` on the mapped region.  If you were writing to `/dev/null`, the `write()` call would return at once without faulting in the pages of the source file, so it would never actually be read from the disk.

Comment: Also, something like GNU `cat` does run on many platforms, but a casual glance at the source code will show lots of `#ifdef`s: it's not literally the same code that runs on all the platforms, and there are plenty of system-dependent sections.

Comment: @NateEldredge: Interesting point, but I was just building on Michael's answer, so you aren't contradicting me so much as you are contradicting Michael.

Comment: @NateEldredge "same source code" != "same preprocessor output" || "same compiler input". And the redirection is still set up by the shell, not by `cat` itself; `cat` just dumps to its stdout.

Comment: I know.  My point is that just because the same source code compiles and runs on both systems, doesn't mean that it isn't doing something OS-dependent!

Comment: @NateEldredge : from memory it's `dd` that's optimised for `/dev/null` output, possibly in exactly the way you describe.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `cat` won't perform its reading using `mmap()`, because that wouldn't work on pipes, sockets etc. - and `cat` definitely needs to work on these!

Comment: @psmears Working with `mmap()` and defaulting to `read()`/`write()` in the case of failure would definitely be an option...

Comment: The recent comments do not appear to be discussing how this answer can be improved. If you want to discuss the internal workings of the GNU `cat` utility, please make a separate question out of that.