# How to avoid creating nohup.out file

Tags: nohup

```
nohup command &> /dev/null &
```

This command still creates `nohup.out` file. Could you please help on how to avoid it?

Comment: What shell are you using to run this command?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10408816/how-do-i-use-the-nohup-command-without-getting-nohup-out

Answer (score 2):

`&>` is not POSIX standard. You need to use this syntax:

```
nohup command >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Related: [Difference between 2>&-, 2>/dev/null, |&, &>/dev/null and >/dev/null 2>&1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/70963/difference-between-2-2-dev-null-dev-null-and-dev-null-21)

Comment: Assuming that they are using `bash`, this is what they are doing.

Comment: @Kusalananda nohup should NOT create a nohup.out file when its stdout is not a tty. Moreover,  `nohup > /dev/null` should be enough. The OP was probably bitten by the `&>` bashism (which will *silently* fail to redirect anything in other shells). This answer is right for that part.