# prevent error if file does not exist

Tags: linux, files, error-handling

I need to get the contents of a file but want to prevent an error if it does not exist.

Is it possible to do something like this?

```
cat my-file.txt || false
```

Comment: do you mean you don't want error to be outputed to screen? just output stderr to /dev/null

Comment: `cat my-file.txt 2>/dev/null` suppresses the error output or `[ -f my-file.txt ] && cat my-file.txt` skips the `cat` if the file is not present or, if you want a `true` exit status, use `[ ! -f my-file.txt ] || cat my-file.txt`

Comment: Consider updating your question with an explanation of what you mean by "preventing an error". It's unclear what error you want to prevent.  Is it the diagnostic message produced by `cat`, the fact that the exit status of your pipeline is non-zero, or do you want to prevent `cat` from even try to process an non-existent file?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Close stderr with `2>&-`:

```
cat my-file.txt 2>&- || false
```

U&L: [Difference between 2>&-, 2>/dev/null, |&, &>/dev/null and >/dev/null 2>&1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/70963/difference-between-2-2-dev-null-dev-null-and-dev-null-21)

Answer (score 5):

You have a few options

1. Avoid printing the file unless it exists, but still allow `cat` to complain if the file exists but cannot be opened

   ```
   [ -f my-file.txt ] && cat my-file.txt
   ```
2. Avoid printing the error message generated if the file cannot be opened for whatever reason, by redirecting *stderr* to "nowhere"

   ```
   cat my-file.txt 2>/dev/null
   ```
3. Avoid setting `$?` to a non-zero exit status, which would indicate that an error occurred.

   ```
    cat my-file.txt || true
   ```

In the first two cases, the next command can be a status test to check if the `cat` was successful. For example

```
cat my-file.txt 2>/dev/null
[ $? -ne 0 ] && echo 'There was an error accessing my-file.txt'
```

Further, this can then be wrapped into a more readable conditional, like this

```
if ! cat my-file.txt 2>/dev/null
then
    echo 'There was an error accessing my-file.txt'
fi
```

In the last case, there is no point in using the command in an `if` statement, as it's successfully hides the exit status of `cat`  in such a way that the exit status of the compound command is *always* zero (it "prevents the error", in a way).